# How to pass ASP.NET authentication to a WCF Service

Tags: asp.net, wcf, authentication

I have a WCF service with basic authentication, which requires a username and password. I am using this service within a thick client and the username and password are stored in the application so can be easily passed.

I now want to use this service with an ASP.NET application. I have security enabled, and it is working fine. I want to know the best way of sending these credentials to my web service. The user name I can get easily using this.User.Identity.Name, but the password is more difficult. Of course I could store it in an encrypted session variable, but is this the right solution? Snippet of code below with the currently hard coded password shown:-

```
MyServiceClient client = new MyServiceClient();
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = this.User.Identity.Name;
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "Password";
```

BTW: This is my first question after many years of finding answers here, so please go easy on me :-)

Answer (score 0):

To enable the authentication service
If you do not already have an ASP.NET Web application, create one.
Add a service file (.svc) to the Web site that contains the following directive to reference the AuthenticationService class, as shown in the following example:
VB

```
<%@ ServiceHost 
  Language="VB"
  Service="System.Web.ApplicationServices.AuthenticationService" 
  Factory="System.Web.ApplicationServices.ApplicationServicesHostFactory" %>
C#
<%@ ServiceHost 
  Language="C#"
  Service="System.Web.ApplicationServices.AuthenticationService" 
  Factory="System.Web.ApplicationServices.ApplicationServicesHostFactory" %>
```

Make the following configuration settings in the Web.config file to configure the service and to require SSL:
Enable the authentication service in the authenticationService element.
Define the endpoint contract in the services element and the service behavior in the behaviors element. Include the bindingNamespace property in the endpoint contract as shown in the following example in order to prevent an exception in some proxy generation tools. For more information about WCF endpoints, see Windows Communication Foundation Endpoints.
Configure the serviceHostingEnvironment element for ASP.NET compatibility. For more information about hosting WCF services, see WCF Services and ASP.NET.
Create a binding in the bindings element that requires SSL. For more information about transport security in WCF, see Transport Security.
The following example shows the system.serviceModel element from a Web.config file that shows the configuration settings described in the previous list.

```
<system.web.extensions>
  <scripting>
    <webServices>
      <authenticationService enabled="true" 
         requireSSL = "true"/>
    </webServices>
  </scripting>
</system.web.extensions>
<system.serviceModel>
  <services>
    <service name="System.Web.ApplicationServices.AuthenticationService"
        behaviorConfiguration="AuthenticationServiceTypeBehaviors">
      <endpoint contract=
        "System.Web.ApplicationServices.AuthenticationService"
        binding="basicHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="userHttps" 
        bindingNamespace="http://asp.net/ApplicationServices/v200"/>
      </service>
  </services>
  <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="userHttps">
                <security mode="Transport" />
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="AuthenticationServiceTypeBehaviors">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment 
    aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
</system.serviceModel>
To configure forms authentication
In the Web.config file, configure the Web application to use forms authentication.
The following example shows the authentication element in a Web.config file that is configured to use forms authentication.
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms cookieless="UseCookies" />
</authentication>
```

The authentication service requires cookies. Therefore, in the authentication element, set the cookieless attribute to "UseCookies". For more information, see ASP.NET Forms Authentication Overview.
Security
If you are passing sensitive user data such as authentication credentials, always access the authentication service over the secure sockets layer (SSL, by using HTTPS protocol). For information about how to set up SSL, see Configuring Secure Sockets Layer (IIS 6.0 Operations Guide).